# Objective with the infinitive

Tags: direct-objects

> They give you exercises to do.

Please explain to me why "to do" is used here, not "to be done".

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81605/there-is-work-to-do-versus-there-is-work-to-be-done

Comment: I agree with Stoney's answer. In case you're interested, "to do" is an infinitival relative clause: "They give you exercises (for you) to do __" where gap, which can be filled with "exercises", is the object of "do". It can also take a subject by adding the subordinator "for", as I've shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Exercises to be done* is passive, with no agent expressed or implied: these exercises must be performed but may be performed by anyone.

*Exercises to do* is active and is parsed as deriving its subject from the recipient: these are exercises are "for **you** to do", not anybody else.